# NetSuite SQL case when

Tags: sql, netsuite

I am trying to write a SQL query in a NetSuite saved search that returns a text value if certain criteria are met, and if they are not met, it moves to the next CASE WHEN statement. Here is what I have:L

```
CASE WHEN {shipstate} IN ('AK','ID','MT','OR','WA') THEN 'Northwest' 
ELSE CASE WHEN {shipstate} IN ('CA','HI','NV','AZ') THEN 'West' 
ELSE CASE WHEN {shipstate} IN ('CO','NM','UT','WY') THEN 'Rockies' 
ELSE CASE WHEN {shipstate} IN ('AR','KS,'LA','OK','TX') THEN 'SO Central' 
ELSE CASE WHEN {shipstate} IN ('IN','KY','MI','OH') THEN 'Great Lakes' 
ELSE CASE WHEN {shipstate} IN ('IA','IL','MN','MO','NE','ND','SD','WI') THEN 'Midwest' 
ELSE CASE WHEN {shipstate} IN ('CT','MA','ME','NH','RI','VT') THEN 'Northeast' 
ELSE 'Southeast' 
END END END END END END END
```

I am not sure if I am inserting the ENDS in the wrong place, but I did have it working earlier with 2 CASE WHEN statements. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can have multiple `when` clauses in a case statement, so you just need one `case` and one `end`, like this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN {shipstate} IN (
        'AK','ID','MT','OR','WA'
        ) THEN 'Northwest' 
    WHEN {shipstate} IN (
        'CA','HI','NV','AZ'
        ) THEN 'West' 
    WHEN {shipstate} IN (
        'CO','NM','UT','WY'
        ) THEN 'Rockies' 
    WHEN {shipstate} IN (
        'AR','KS','LA','OK','TX'
        ) THEN 'SO Central' 
    WHEN {shipstate} IN (
        'IN','KY','MI','OH'
        ) THEN 'Great Lakes' 
    WHEN {shipstate} IN (
        'IA','IL','MN','MO','NE','ND','SD','WI'
        ) THEN 'Midwest' 
    WHEN {shipstate} IN (
        'CT','MA','ME','NH','RI','VT'
        ) THEN 'Northeast' 
    ELSE 'Southeast' 
END
```

BTW, you forget a `'` in one of your `IN` condition.